# How to enable javascript window.focus() in IE9

Tags: javascript, html

I've used:

```
var win = window.open('http://www.google.co.uk','foo');
```

to open a new window I've then navigated back to the orginal window leaving the new window open and used:

```
win.focus();
```

I expected the browser to switch back to the foo window how ever IE9 ignores it and stays on the current window.  Works in chrome and IE6 I'm assuming this may have been disabled as a security risk. Is there a way to enable window.focus in IE9 via security settings or registry settings?

This is my full code:

```
<a onclick="OpenWindow();">Click here to open a window</a><br />
<a onclick="SelectWindow();">click here to switch to window</a>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var win;

function OpenWindow() {
    win = window.open("http://www.google.co.uk", "foo");
}

function SelectWindow() {
    win.focus();
}

</script>
```

Comment: I've added the full code but i dont know what you want me to format. Looks formatted to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a **known bug** in **Internet Explorer 9**. Check out the article, [A web page may fail to get focus in Windows Internet Explorer 9](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600156) for more info.

#### Registry Fix

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\
Type: REG_DWORD
Name: HangRecovery
Value: 0
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the bug but unfortunately that registry change has had no effect on my situation.

Comment: Lets see. Will find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the following has worked for me on all browsers since 2003:

```
function popupHelp(helpUrl) {
    helpWin = window.open(helpUrl, "help",
            "height=500,width=500,scrollbars,resizable,toolbar,status,menubar");
    if (helpWin != null) {
        setTimeout("helpWin.focus()",100);
    }
}

...

<a href="javascript:popupHelp('help.jsp')">Help</a>
```

As of 2013-08-27 it seems to be the feature list on the window.open() call that forces/allows IE 8, 9, and 10 to give the window focus a second time.  I say window because it also forces IE to open in a window, not a tab (Chrome uses a tab, Firefox works like IE).  I wish all browsers worked like Chrome in this regard.  They all seem to open a new window with target="_blank" just fine, cluttering the users desktop with open windows, but reusing an existing window is something they don't want to do.